# Porque ngx-mat-select-search não funciona com meus dados dinâmicos?

Tags: angular, typescript

Eu instalei o [ngx-mat-select-search](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mat-select-search) e segui o exemplo do [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/bithost-gmbh/ngx-mat-select-search-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

O exemplo funcionou perfeitamente, da mesma forma que está no *stackblitz*. Depois disso mudei meu código para carregar os dados dinamicamente. Carreguei os dados normalmente e os valores são listados na UI, mas a barra de filtragem não faz nada e não ocorre nenhum erro.

**HTML:**

```
<mat-form-field class="selectList-full-width">
    <mat-select [formControl]="selectTechnicalRoomCtrl" [placeholder]="'SelectTechnicalRoom' | localize" #singleSelect>
        <mat-option>
        <ngx-mat-select-search [formControl]="selectTechnicalRoomFilterCtrl" [placeholderLabel]="'Search' | localize"></ngx-mat-select-search>
        </mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let technicalRoom of technicalRooms" [value]="technicalRoom">
        {{technicalRoom.nameRoom}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<div class="p-r-25 btn-toolbar">
    <button style="margin-left: 10px; padding: 0 1em;" mat-raised-button color="primary" >{{ 'ListPoints' | localize }}</button>    
</div>
```

**TS:**

```
export class HomeComponent extends AppComponentBase implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
    technicalRooms: IdNameTechnicalRoomDto[] = [];
    public selectTechnicalRoomCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();
    public selectTechnicalRoomFilterCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();

    /** list of itens filtered by search keyword */
    public filteredTechnicalRooms: ReplaySubject<IdNameTechnicalRoomDto[]> = new ReplaySubject<IdNameTechnicalRoomDto[]>(1);

    @ViewChild('singleSelect', { static: true }) singleSelect: MatSelect;

    protected _onDestroy = new Subject<void>();

    constructor(
        injector: Injector,
        private _technicalRoomsService: TechnicalRoomServiceProxy,
    ) {
        super(injector);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.list();

      // set initial selection
    this.selectTechnicalRoomCtrl.setValue(this.technicalRooms[10]);

    // load the initial itens list
    this.filteredTechnicalRooms.next(this.technicalRooms.slice());

    // listen for search field value changes
    this.selectTechnicalRoomFilterCtrl.valueChanges
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._onDestroy))
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.filterTechnicalRooms();
      });
      }

      list(): void {

          this._technicalRoomsService
              .getList()
              .pipe()
              .subscribe(
                data => this.technicalRooms = data["result"]
              );
      }

      ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.setInitialValue();
      }

      ngOnDestroy() {
        this._onDestroy.next();
        this._onDestroy.complete();
      }

      /**
       * Sets the initial value after the filteredTechnicalRooms are loaded initially
       */
      protected setInitialValue() {
        this.filteredTechnicalRooms
          .pipe(take(1), takeUntil(this._onDestroy))
          .subscribe(() => {
            this.singleSelect.compareWith = (a: IdNameTechnicalRoomDto, b: IdNameTechnicalRoomDto) => a && b && a.id === b.id;
          });
      }

      protected filterTechnicalRooms() {
        if (!this.technicalRooms) {
          return;
        }
        // get the search keyword
        let search = this.selectTechnicalRoomFilterCtrl.value;
        if (!search) {
          this.filteredTechnicalRooms.next(this.technicalRooms.slice());
          return;
        } else {
          search = search.toLowerCase();
        }
        // filter the technicalRooms
        this.filteredTechnicalRooms.next(
          this.technicalRooms.filter(technicalRoom => technicalRoom.nameRoom.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1)
        );
      }

}
```

Comment: coloca um ngif technicalRooms  pra esperar ele carregar

Comment: @EduardoVargas, fiz oque sugeriu e deu o erro `Cannot set property 'compareWith' of undefined`

Comment: vc fez *ngIf="technicalRooms"?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo. Já consegui solucionar, se ninguém responder coloco a minha solução aqui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou compartilhar a solução aqui que consegui junto a dica do Eduardo Vargas nos comentários.

Consegui solucionar meu problema seguindo as instruções do [macjohnny](https://github.com/macjohnny), [dessa issue no GitHub.](https://github.com/bithost-gmbh/ngx-mat-select-search/issues/83#issuecomment-443410145)

De forma resumida, o problema era que eu precisava carregar minha lista filtrada antes de setar ela no `input`.

a solução dada na issue é essa:

```
@Input() set data(data: any[]) {
  this._data = data;
  // load the initial entity list
  this.filteredEntities.next(this.data.slice());
}
get data(): any[] {
  return this._data;
}
private _data: any[];
```

Mas antes criei um componente no angular, conforme ideia do autor da *issue*, pra sempre que eu precisar usar-lo. Chamei esse componente de `select-search`.

### A solução completa ficou assim:

**select-search.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="entityFilterCtrl">
    <mat-select [formControl]="entityCtrl" #singleSelect (selectionChange)="onChange($event)">
        <ngx-mat-select-search 
            [formControl]="entityFilterCtrl" 
            [placeholderLabel]="'Search'"
            [noEntriesFoundLabel]="'Not found'">
        </ngx-mat-select-search>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let entity of filteredEntities | async" [value]="entity.url">{{entity.name}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**select-search.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Input, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSelect } from '@angular/material';
import { ReplaySubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { takeUntil, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-select-search',
  templateUrl: './select-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select-search.component.css']
})
export class SelectSearchComponent implements OnInit {

  /** control for the selected entity */
  public entityCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();

  /** control for the MatSelect filter keyword */
  public entityFilterCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();

  /** list of entities filtered by search keyword */
  public filteredEntities: ReplaySubject<any[]> = new ReplaySubject<any[]>(1);

  @ViewChild('singleSelect', { static: true }) singleSelect: MatSelect;

  /** Subject that emits when the component has been destroyed. */
  private _onDestroy = new Subject<void>();

  @Input() set data(data: any[]) {
    this._data = data;
    // load the initial entity list
    this.filteredEntities.next(this.data.slice());
  }
  get data(): any[] {
    return this._data;
  }
  private _data: any[];

  @Output() onSelectionChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // listen for search field value changes
    this.entityFilterCtrl.valueChanges
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._onDestroy))
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.filterEntities();
      });

  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.setInitialValue();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._onDestroy.next();
    this._onDestroy.complete();
  }

  onChange($event) {
    this.onSelectionChange.emit($event);
  }

  private setInitialValue() {
    this.filteredEntities
      .pipe(take(1), takeUntil(this._onDestroy))
      .subscribe(() => {
        // setting the compareWith property to a comparison function
        // triggers initializing the selection according to the initial value of
        // the form control (i.e. _initializeSelection())
        // this needs to be done after the filteredEntities are loaded initially
        // and after the mat-option elements are available
        if(this.singleSelect)
          this.singleSelect.compareWith = (a: any, b: any) => a.url === b.url;
      });
  }

  private filterEntities() {
    if (!this.data) {
      return;
    }
    // get the search keyword
    let search = this.entityFilterCtrl.value;
    if (!search) {
      this.filteredEntities.next(this.data.slice());
      return;
    } else {
      search = search.toLowerCase();
    }
    // filter the entitys
    this.filteredEntities.next(
      this.data.filter(entity => entity.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1)
    );
  }

}
```

**E para usa-lo:**

```
 <app-select-search class="selectList-full-width" [data]="pokemons"></app-select-search>
```

[Coloquei no meu GitHub como exemplo](https://github.com/Wurthma/ExampleNgxMatSelectSearch) e também [importei para o StackBlitz para poder ver funcionando](https://stackblitz.com/github/Wurthma/ExampleNgxMatSelectSearch).